# Weird imperfect table, horizontal line overflow

Tags: tables, rules

I've this weird problem where the horizontal lines in a table are overflowing. It might be due to one of the many packages, I'm not sure. Is there a way to forcefully fix the table border.

The latex code used to generate the table is this

```
\begin{table}%[h]
\caption{test} % title of Table
\centering  % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
T & t1  & t2  & t3 & t4 \\ \hline
a & 10\%  & 40\% & 70\% & 95\% \\ \hline
b & 20\%  & 50\% & 80\% & 98\% \\ \hline
c & 30\%  & 650\% & 90\% & 99\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Sample image is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VjCB.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: This might be caused by the same problem Heiko Oberdiek addresses in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85868/4427)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\ \hline` (you were missing a slash prior to the `\hline`):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h]

\caption{test} % title of Table 
\centering % used for centering table 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 
T & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 \\ \hline 
a & 10\% & 40\% & 70\% & 95\% \\ \hline 
b & 20\% & 50\% & 80\% & 98\% \\ \hline 
c & 30\% & 650\% & 90\% & 99\% \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \\ is not the problem. Also some of the tables have this problem while others are fine. I don't know why the line is not wrapping properly. The text is small and not overflowing the cell.

Comment: @palhello: Ok, the image was not there when I posted my answer based on your original MWE. That is probably an artifact of your viewer. Try viewing in Acrobat.

Comment: I don't see any change in code. I'm using other packages and it must be ruining this. Any way to fix this without going into the packages ? I am viewing it in the acrobat viewer. This is really weird. Some tables are perfect while others are imperfect. I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: You need to post a complete compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate package.  The code you posted does not show the problem. Also try zooming in and make sure the you still see the problem.