# Compiling the latex->dvips->ps2pdf with dvips -Ppdf

Tags: pstricks, animations, animate, dvips, ps2pdf

The documents I create heavily depend on postscripts (I use `pstricks` quite a lot).  I've had some issues with resolution, and [it's been recommended to try using `dvips -Ppdf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85868/22413).  But recently, I've been using the `animate` package, which happily now supports compiling along the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` route.

I've now noticed in several places, such as the `animate` package documentation and in a solution to [Move-around box in PDF display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108998/22413), that the switch `-Ppdf` not be used.  But nothing is said why this should not be done.

Could someone explain why/when this switch should not be used?

Comment: The file `config.pdf` was used to create an optimized ps output which is then used by Adobes Distiller. For `ps2pdf` (Ghostscript) it is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is loosely explained in the **Bugs** section of the animate doc.

`-Ppdf` loads `config.pdf` during DVI to PS conversion and sets the dots-per-inch resolution (DPI) in the intermediate Postscript to the value of `8000`. This is equivalent to using `dvips` option `-D8000`.

The only benefit of this high resolution is related to fonts generation in case of Type-3 (pixel-) fonts. Nowadays, Type-1 (vector-) fonts are used, which will always make use of the maximum available resolution of the printing device in order to create sharp contours of the glyphs on paper. 8000 dpi were and are just big enough for the commercially available ink-jet and laser printer hardware.

Another side effect of the DPI setting is related to transformation matrix calculation of graphical objects (XObjects) during PS to PDF conversion. (Animation frames and the move-around tooltips are saved as XObjects in the resulting PDF.) Ghostscript's `ps2pdf` tends to calculate transformation matrices whose elements have very large values. While these values are numerically correct they are too large for Adobe Reader if the DPI resolution of the intermediate Postscript was set to `8000` via `-Ppdf` or `-D8000`. As a consequence, Adobe Reader displays graphical objects at the wrong position or poorly scaled.

Therefore, it is recommended to either not use `-Ppdf` with `dvips` or to override the DPI setting of `config.pdf` by running `dvips` as

```
dvips -Ppdf -D1200 ...
```

---

The value of 2636 dpi (`dvips -D2636`), seems to be critical here.

Consider the following code example which produces a clickable button in Adobe Reader. The boxed string 'Hello!' is distilled into an XObject and used as the button face:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\mediabutton[jsaction={app.alert('Hello!');}]{\fbox{Hello!}}
\end{document}
```

If the PDF was produced with `latex` --> `dvips -D2636` --> `ps2pdf` the button is perfectly visible in Adobe Reader. However, at any higher resolution, e. g. `dvips -D2637` or `dvips -Ppdf`, the button face disappears (although the button itself remains functional).